# create and submit form dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is so basic, but I spent sometimes now and couldn't figure it out.

I am trying to create a form with one hidden input and submit it to "test.php" page using jQuery. However, I can't access this form when, so I am not sure where is the problem!!

This is jQuery to create and submit the form:

```
$('#submitForm').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Create a Form
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('id','queryForm');
    f.setAttribute('name','queryForm');
    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('action',"test.php");

    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    i.setAttribute('name',"query");
    i.setAttribute('id',"queryId");
    i.setAttribute("value", "success");

    f.appendChild(i);
    document.body.appendChild(f);

    //Send the Form
    f.submit();
});
```

In "test.php" I have the code bellow. I tried to print the form length to make sure I submitted the form correctly but I get 0!!

```
<body>
<script>
  var formlength = document.forms.length;
  alert(formlength); // I get 0
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code should work as expected .. meaning this create a form and submit it right away to `test.php` . Where are you trying to "check" your form? If you're trying to find it in "test.php", you won't because it passed data to it, not the form itself ..

Comment: @rorofromfrance test.php has nothing except the javascript above where I check the formlength. It shows 0 which from my understanding means there is no form, right? I tried getElementbyId("queryId") and got nothing too!

Comment: where are you checking `document.forms.length`, check it before `f.submit()`, you should get `1`. You can't access the form once it is submitted, coz the page will reload!

Comment: Where do you load this code? In head or before the ending body tag? The DOM might not be loaded yet.

Comment: The edit wont work, there are no forms in that page.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson So how can I get the element "query" in test.php?

Comment: That's server-side so with php, ruby, python etc. Or i you parse the `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery code is fine. Put this line in the test.php file to test it out:

```
<?php echo $_POST['query']; ?>
```

It should output "success" on the test.php page

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms.length` counts the number of `<form>`-tags not the submitted data.

As of you're using php (put it in test.php).

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['query']) ) {
   echo htmlspecialchars( $_POST['query'] );
}
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/428GQ/1/ . I've commented out the submit and changed the hidden field to a text (just to make sure it works). Now add the above code the test.php and watch it work (of course you will have to remove the comments first).

Comment: I think I need the $("sumbitForm") because I call this function when a button clicks. All I need is get the element "query" in test.php. Not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I altered your code to use more Jquery and as advice by [ Niclas Larsson] put it in the footer.. please check this

```
                    //Create a Form
                    var $f = document.createElement('<form></form>');
                    $f.attr('id','queryForm');
                    $f.attr('name','queryForm');
                    $f.attr('method',"post");
                    $f.attr('action',"test.php");


                    var $i = $( '<input />' );
                    $i.attr("type", "hidden");
                    $i.attr('name',"query");
                    $i.attr('id',"queryId");
                    $i.attr("value", "success");

                    $f.append(i);
                    $('body').append(f);

                    console.log($f);

                    //Send the Form
                    $f.submit();
```